# LED display resolution dpi

Tags: led, lcd, oled, resolution

I had a question about the resolution of an OLED display. It's says the resolution is 128x128 dots under the display format in the datasheet sheet of the OLED. Does this mean that there are 128 dots per inch horizontally and also 128 per inch vertically on the display ?
How does this convert to pixels and pixels per inch ?

Answer (score 2):

No - that means the total number of pixels is 128 in each direction.  The pixel density depends upon the size of the display.

What is the size of the display?

For the given size of approximately 29 * 29 mm that results in a resolution of ~113 DPI.

Comment: @KevinWhitethe overall dimensions of display is 33.8 x 34.00 x 1.60 mm. The viewable area of display is 28.855 x 28.864 mm. The active area of the display is 26.855 x 26.864 mm . It is 1.5 inch diagonal.